# Simultaneous WiFi connection to multiple nodes

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I'm designing a WiFi module based on a ATMEL WiFi radio chip, and I'm wondering if there are any limitations in the amount of IP-connections I can establish.

I would like my module to be able to simultaneously connect (through an AP) to at least 5 IP adresses. Can anyone give some more insight on this topic.